# Error: Argument 'HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I get the following error:

Error: Argument 'HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined assertArg@

This is what my code: 
**in main.js,**

```
var my_app = angular.module("my_app",[]);

var config = function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider      
        .otherwise({
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            });
        };

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
my_app.config(config);
```

**in HomeCtrl.js,**

```
my_app.controller("HomeCtrl",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.hello = "Doe";
}]);
```

**in home.html,**

```
This is the home page using angular.
<br>
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
Value of "hello": {{hello}}
</div>
```

**in layouts/application.html.erb,**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="my_app">
<head>
  <title>FirstAngularOnRails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view>
    <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What mistake i have done here.,

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please ensure that the `HtmlCtrl.js` is included in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that your page includes HomeCtrl.js

It looks as though you are only including your application.js file. If you are using asset pipeline you may reference it there.

Comment: I jus included 
<%= javascript_include_tag "angular/controllers/HomeCtrl"%> in my application.html.erb file and solved my problem. I have also tried including <%= javascript_include_tag "HomeCtrl"%> earlier (before asking this question here), but i failed to include the absolute path of the HomeCtrl.js. That is what the issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In main.js ensure you are telling angular about the controllers module. 

i.e. **HomeCtrl.js** should have the following as the first line:

```
var my_app = angular.module('my_app.homeCtrl', []);
```

Which lets you put the following in **main.js** to tell angular about the controller module you created (I included ngRoute since I didn't see it in your above code):

```
var my_app = angular.module("my_app",[
"ngRoute",
"my_app.homeCtrl"
]);
```

Also, ensure your **HomeCtrl.js** file is being loaded after your **main.js** file as Shaun said.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions man!! 

Also, If we define var my_app = angular.module() in both HomeCtrl.js and main.js, then there will be conflict right.? which "my_app" is the actual application.

Comment: There will not be a conflict. I was testing it in a live application that I have. If I eliminate the line from the controller file, I get a module cannot be injected error. The one in main.js is the actual application. You can define the one in controller as any var you want. It's only applicable to that js file. I actually define my application name in the main.js(app.js for me) i.e. var app = angular.module('OneCrazyApp' ['app.services']); Then in the controllers, directives, services, I start off with var app = angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource']);

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your information.! will try to follow in my future applications. But, in my current sample application, it works without having another var my_app in my controller.

Comment: It's cool that it works in yours without it. I wonder if rails compiles differently than the tools I use. I've never played with RoR.